# PHP split for each statement and float half of the data right

Tags: php, css

I have the code below to split my for each statement into two separate divs:

```
<?php
    $previousLetter = false;
?>
<?php 
$i=1; // have a counter variable
foreach($this->clubs as $clubs) : ?>
    <?php
    $firstLetter = substr($clubs->club_name, 0, 1);
    if ($firstLetter != $previousLetter) {
    if($i==1){
        echo "<div class="left_class">"; // open left div
    }
    ?>
        <h3 id="club-link-header"><u><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></u></h3>
    <?php } ?>
        <a id="club-link" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'club-description', 'action' => 'index', 'club_id' => $clubs->id));?>"><br />
        <?php echo $this->escape($clubs->club_name);?></a>
    <?php $previousLetter = $firstLetter; ?>
<?php 
    if($i==25){
        echo "</div>"; //close left div
        echo "<div class="right_class">"; // open right div
    }

    if($i==50){
        echo "</div>"; //close right div
    }

$i++; // increment the counter variable for each loop
endforeach; 
?>
```

The HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="top">
            <a id="admin-link" href="/MN/public/index.php/admin/index/id/1"></a>
    <div id="logged-in-as">
        Hello! ric89. <a href="/MN/public/index.php/auth/logout">Logout</a>    </div>

</div>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div id="social">
                <a id="fb" href="#"><img src="/MN/public/images/fb.png" /></a>
                <a id="twitter" href="#"><img src="/MN/public/images/twitter.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="nav">
                <div id="nav-left">
                    <a href="/MN/public/index.php/index/index/id/1">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div id="nav-middle">
                    <a id="clubs-link" href="/MN/public/index.php/clubs/index/id/1">Clubs</a>
                    </div>
                <div id="nav-right">
                    <a id="admin-link" href="/MN/public/index.php/admin/index/id/1">Admin</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="logo">

             </div>

    </div>

</div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Clubs</h1>
           //database content is echo'd here, 50 items like this:
           <h3 id="club-link-header"><u>5</u></h3>
        <a id="club-link" href="/MN/public/index.php/club-description/index/id/1/club_id/1"><br />
    5th Avenue</a>
    </div>
<div id="footer">
        <p id="footer-text">created & designed by <a href="http://www.richardgregson.info" target="_blank">Richard Knight-Gregson</a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
/*Content styles */

.clubs-left {
    width: 450px;
}

.clubs-right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
}

.right_class {
    float: right;
    width: 450px;
}

.left_class {
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is an image of the problem -> http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/84/screenshot20120426at211.png/ The footer should be 100% width.

The issue is I can't float the div right without breaking the layout as the right div needs to be on top of the left in the code but doing so will break the PHP.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, does that code works or gives you a Parse error? ex: echo "<div class="right_class">";  <-- Notes that there's an unexpected T_STRING in there!

Comment: No thats not coming up..

Comment: instead of echoing everything, stock datas into a variable and echo once at the end of your foreach. it will be easier to deal with your div problem this way.

Comment: how about absolutely positioning the divs instead of floating them?

Comment: this code alone seems to break the footer of the page.. If I absolutely position them I get the footer in the header..

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem that you are describing seams to be purely cosmetic, I believe that you need to clear the float to allow the document to continue its normal rendering:

After your `<div class="right_class">...</div>`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on, since you are requesting help for a format issue, and you are giving a PHP cycle as the source code! Do you have a link for us to look at? Or at least edit your question and place the CSS and the surrounding HTML that goes with that PHP.

Comment: added the HTML and CSS that I think is relevant.

Comment: Check this link to see if it's what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/UvSSV/1/  (drag the preview panel to see it better)

Comment: Yeah I have managed to get that far.. But my footer width gets broken.. it used to be 100% now it seems to be the width of the two divs combined.. 900px heres an image to show you -> http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/1343/screenshot20120427at211.png its obviously something else in my code, but do you have any idea what causes these kind of synthetic errors?

Comment: If you want your footer with the width of the screen, just apply some CSS to it: footer {width:100%;}  If your code is fairly similar to my Fiddle example, it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't something like this be more efficient?

Break up your list by alphabet to start...

```
var glossary=array();
var $half=(int)count($this=>clubs);

 var $count=0;

foreach ($this->clubs as $clubs){
        $glossary[substr($clubs->club_name, 0, 1)][] = $clubs;
    }
    # Start a definition list.  (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp)
    echo'<dl>';
    foreach ($glossary as $letter => $clubs){
        $count++;
        $class=($count>=$half)?'float_left':'float_right';
    # list all the clbs broken down by letter
        echo"<dt class='$class'>$letter</dt>";
        foreach ($clubs as $club)
        {

            echo"<dd class='$class'>
                <a id='club-link' href='" . $this->url(array('controller' => 'club-description', 'action' => 'index', 'club_id' => $club->id)) . "'>
            " . $this->escape($clubs->club_name) .
                "</a>
            </dd>";
        }
    }
    echo '</dl>';
```

and the css:

```
dl{
   width:100%;
}

.float_left{
   width:49%;
   float:left;
   clear:left;
}
.float_right{
   width:49%;
   float:right;
   clear:right;
}
```

this way after you hit the halfway point in clubs, the dt and dd elements stack on the right side, and the list will automatically balance, no matter how many clubs you have.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure breaking left/right on a numbered sequence would be particularly helpful since that will force rendering in the expected way only at a given known resolution. Assume I have a tablet and it looks right when held in landscape. what happens when I tip the tablet to portrait?

Comment: the information that I am splitting is a maximum of 12 characters wide, so I don't think this would be an issue.. It looks daft at the moment as there is a lot of white space..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the footer was inside the content div and I hadn't closed the content div properly one more extra  before the footer starts was all it needed! Sorry to waste your time..